# Python 2.7 Object-Orientated __init__ method

Tags: windows, class, python-2.7, spyder

I've just read the explanation in **Think Python** about `__init__` methods for classes. However, I tried to initiate a Prime Generator function I made for Project Euler.net and I continued to get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\-------\Desktop\Primes.py", line 54, in <module>
    Primes.__main__()
TypeError: unbound method __main__() must be called with Primes instance as first argument (got nothing instead)
```

I pulled it up in a console, and I finally got it to work by calling this:

```
primes = Primes()
primes.primegenerator(some number)
```

It then ran properly. How do I get this behavior to work in the `__init__` method?

Here is the full code:

```
class Primes():
    def __init__(self, primes = []):
        self.primes = primes
    def primegenerator(self,limit):
        'Generates primes to a given limit'
        primes = [3]
        i = 3 # i is the counter
        while len(primes) < limit - 1:
            for prime in primes:
                if i % prime == 0:
                    i += 2
                    break
                elif prime != primes[-1]:
                    continue
                else:
                    primes.append(i)
                    i += 2
                    break
        primes.insert(0,2)
        return primes
def main(self):
    limit = input('Enter a limit please: ')
    primes = Primes.primegenerator(limit)
    print '-------------------------' * 2
    print The answer is: %d' %primes[-1]
    print 'The sum of the primes is: %d' %sum(primes)
    print print '-------------------------' * 2
```

Would this even be a good program to add an **init** method to?

Comment: What are `__int__ classes` ? (classes that just define `__int__`?)

Comment: And why exactly do you have a class in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is in `Primes.__main__()` - you need to pass an instance like
`Primes.__main__(self)` or `Primes.__main__(primes)`

but for a full answer you would have to show the full code.

It is not a good idea to do

`Primes = Primes()`

before that statement, Primes is a class (or maybe a function), afterwards it is an instance.
Better say

`primes = Primes()`

Comment: I apologise, I have mistyped my question. I have appended it now, and also added by entire code to be more concise. My problem is understanding Initialization in classes.